# SQL query optimization for MySql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, optimization

I have 3 table: user , company  and deal.

One user may own several companies. Deal is made between the 2 companies. I need a list of deals, which involved my company.

Deals must contain the following fields: partner_company_id,my_company_id,partner_photo,partner_name,deal_about.

Language code: PHP.
Database: Mysql.

**1.List of my company I can get by user ID**.

```
user_id = 22;

companyList = query('SELECT company_id FROM company WHERE user_id = ?', user_id);
```

**2. Then i get deal list where my_company_id is company_first_id**

```
 list1 = query('SELECT u.name AS partner_name, u.photo AS partner_photo, d.first_company_id AS 

    my_company_id , d.second_company_id AS partner_company_id,d.about AS deal_about FROM deal AS d

    INNER JOIN company AS c ON c.company_id = d.second_company_id

    INNER JOIN user AS u ON u.user_ud = c.user_id 

    WHERE d.company_first_id IN (?)', companyList);
```

**3. Then i get deal list where my_company_id is company_second_id**

```
 list2 = query('SELECT u.name AS partner_name, u.photo AS partner_photo, d.first_company_id AS 

partner_company_id , d.second_company_id AS my_company_id,d.about AS deal_about FROM deal AS d
    INNER JOIN company AS c ON c.company_id = d.first_company_id
    INNER JOIN user AS u ON u.user_ud = c.user_id 
    WHERE d.company_second_id IN (?)', companyList);
```

**4. then i marge to array and set limit list**

```
list = array_marge(list1,list2);
result = array_slice (list ,0 , 10);
```

**HELP please optimize this queries.**

**THANKS.**

DATABASE SCHEME

```
      user      |    company     |      deal     |
--------------------------------------------------         
user_d          | company_id     | deal_id
photo           | user_id        |first_company_id
name            | about          |second_company_id 
                |                |description
```

Comment: I think it is quite rude to ask someone to do all the work for you. Nice question would be: I have this idea for optimizing, will this work or do you know some improvements? Or: Is there a good book about query optimization?

Comment: We're not here to do your job. Do you have any reason to suspect these queries CAN be optimized? Any ideas on where to begin?

Answer (score 0):

Are your queries so slow? They don't look slow (provided you have indexes on all IDs of course).

However, you can save one database access by combining the two deal queries. Either you simply select `query1 UNION ALL query1` or you do it in one pass:

```
select
  u.name AS partner_name, 
  u.photo AS partner_photo, 
  d.my_company_id,
  d.partner_company_id,
  d.about AS deal_about 
from
(
  select 
    about, 
    case when company_first_id in (?) then
      company_first_id 
    else 
      company_second_id 
    end as my_company_id,
    case when company_first_id in (?) then
       company_second_id 
    else 
      company_first_id
    end as partner_company_id
  from deal
  where company_first_id in (?) OR d.company_second_id in (?)
) as d
inner join company as c on c.company_id = d.partner_company_id
inner join user as u on u.user_ud = c.user_id
```